# Why doesn't Tampermonkey process my user script for some Jira issues?

Tags: ajax, google-chrome, jira, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

Our recent upgrade from Jira Server v6.x to v7.x resulted in timestamps switching from absolute (24/Oct/18 11:37 AM) to relative (2 days ago) display.  I know v7 has a global setting for relative vs. absolute timestamps but enough of my teammates like the relative timestamps that we can't make everyone happy with either system-wide setting.  I'm trying to write a user script (for Tampermonkey) to fix the display in the browser.  That way users who want absolute timestamps can get them without disturbing others.

I have the logic working.  If I go to `https://<myJiraServer>/browse/TICKET-123`,  all of the timestamps are processed.  However, common scenarios leave timestamps unprocessed.

- if I search for issues then click the issue key or summary to view issue details, the script doesn't seem to kick in.
- if I refresh the resulting issue, the script runs but the back button doesn't get me to the search results.
- if I shift-click the issue in the search results, the issue opens in a new window and the script runs

I've tried all the possible `run-at` settings but there seems to be something magic about how Jira replaces the search results page with the issue details that doesn't trip any of them.  I wonder about injecting the script at `document-start` and having it rerun my processing with a timer or something.  Any better thoughts?

Comment: You need to provide either a [mcve] or/and a link we can see and test against, at a minimum.